# Android exception - Unknown origin (possibly widget)

Tags: android, exception

I have the following Android exception. It is reported by Bugsense and I cannot find out where it comes from as there is no reference to any class of my app.

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
>   at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView$ListItemAccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AbsListView.java:2512)
>   at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:4849)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(LinearLayout.java:1768)
>   at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:4812)
>   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:825)
>   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:848)
>   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:848)
>   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:848)
>   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:848)
>   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:734)
>   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:205)
>   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$400(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:49)
>   at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:985)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I do suspect it has something to do with updating a widget. Any ideas on how to trace?

Answer (score 0):

Got similar Nullpointer with a Google map view. 
try and turn off any accessibility options enabled on your phone? 
And there is a another accessibility bug reported on the Android Issues tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55933)

It looks like there is no easy way to turn of accessibility from code, except for overriding the addChildrenForAccessibility method in a custom view. (see above link)