# What triggers a call to AccessibilityInteractionController.performAccessibilityActionUiThread on Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

There is a crash on a Samsung Galaxy S 7 Edge when a user is interacting with an `EditText` that has a `LengthFilter` `InputFilter` applied. How would a user cause the method `AccessibilityInteractionController.performAccessibilityActionUiThread` to be called?

I looked at the source of `AccessibilityInteractionController` but I cannot find good documentation of how a user would trigger that method.

My crash's stack trace is similar to what is posted in these questions:

- [Android exception - Unknown origin (possibly widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050642/android-exception-unknown-origin-possibly-widget)
- [My Android App has IndexOutOfBoundsException,how to solved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587762/my-android-app-has-indexoutofboundsexception-how-to-solved/34587842)

Comment: could it be that you need to call a `Activity.RunOnUIThread` when performing whatever action it is you are doing?

Comment: from this [website](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2014/04/06/run-code-on-mainui-thread-on-android/#.V7c2T1dSZuY): "Android’s UI components are not thread safe so one may need to update Views or other UI components from a secondary thread when returning from an asynchronous database query or a web service call.  If you run the code from a secondary thread you might see that the code crashes almost on each try."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into Android's [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177209), it seems that this issue is due to password managers using Accessibility events to generate passwords. However, generated password don't respect the `maxLength` property, causing the crash.

The suggested solution seems to work: creating a subclass, and using that instead. (Copying the code for reference)

```
public class SafePinEntryEditText extends EditText {

    public SafePinEntryEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SafePinEntryEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SafePinEntryEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public SafePinEntryEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int index) {
        // prevent index out of bounds caused by AccessibilityService events
        if (index > length()) {
            index = length();
        }
        super.setSelection(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int start, int stop) {
        // prevent index out of bounds caused by AccessibilityService events
        if (start > length()) {
            start = length();
        }
        if (stop > length()) {
            stop = length();
        }
        super.setSelection(start, stop);
    }
}
```